# How to create radio buttons on a folium map without removing the tiles?

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to generate a folium map with various feature groups. I want two of these groups to appear as radio buttons.

I've tried setting the attribute "overlay" to False when creating a FeatureGroup, but then the map tiles disappear when I select the FeatureGroup.

Here is my code:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=6)

techno = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Techno")
m.add_child(techno)

group2G = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(techno, name="2G")
m.add_child(group2G)
group3G = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(techno, name="3G")
m.add_child(group3G)

qualification = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Qualification", show=False)
m.add_child(qualification)

group_home = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(qualification, name="Home")
m.add_child(group_home)
group_work = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(qualification, name="Work")
m.add_child(group_work)

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
```

I would like to change the techno and qualification FeatureGroups to be radio buttons, so that only one can be selected at a time.